# Differentiating between left and right shift key

Tags: key-bindings

I have a bad habit of using the shift key of the same side of the keyboard as the letter when tying uppercase letters. To type a `D`, for example, I press the left shift with my left pinky and `d` with  my left index finger. It is better to use the right shift in combination with keys on the left hand side of the keyboard, and *vise versa*.

To get rid of this habit I would like to disable the combinations of either shift key with keys on the same side of the keyboard. I can map shift-d with `<S-d>`, but this applies to both shift keys. Is there a to apply only to the right hand shift key?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Vim to differentiate a `A` (`S-a` either with right or left shift). Maybe try looking for your terminal or keyboard configuration.

Comment: Just a note - *why* is this a bad habit? Type however works for you, and is most comfortable.

Comment: @frugle It is a bad habit because it is uncomfortable and often makes me stretch my fingers in awkward positions that interrupt my typing. For me, the beauty of vim is how it allows for speed and flow, and this habit breaks that.

Comment: Fair point. But as note RE: speed and flow, wont you break your flow if you habitually type <LShift>+d, which wont output anything, and then have to remember to use your <Rshift>+d mapping, instead? And there are times when using <LShift>+d could be warranted (One handed typing, or if your right hand is on a numpad, etc.), which this mapping will prevent you from doing, presenting further potential disruptions down the line. It seems that this mapping causes a circular problem (Problem A causes symptom B, Fix problem A with solution C that also causes symptom B). Better to fix the root problem

Comment: The idea is to implement the mapping only to unlearn the bad habit and then remove the mapping. I've done this before with some success. I have a mapping <jj> to delete the last word while in insert mode to avoid having to repeatedly smash backspace. To get the hapit of using it I also had to map thee successive presses on backspace to do nothing. When I had learnt not to flail at backspace I removed this second mapping.

Comment: Think HardMode.

Comment: If it's xterm maybe it can be configured to send different key sequences on left and right shift, although I haven't tested -- [key bindings - Mapping Ctrl with equal sign - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Vim FAQ 20.4. "I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4):

> 1) First make sure, the key is passed correctly to Vim. To determine
>   if this is the case, put Vim in Insert mode and then hit Ctrl-V (or
>   Ctrl-Q if your Ctrl-V is remapped to the paste operation (e.g. on
>   Windows if you are using the mswin.vim script file) followed by your
>   key.
>
> If nothing appears in the buffer (and assuming that you have
>   'showcmd' on, ^V remains displayed near the bottom right of the Vim
>   screen), then Vim doesn't get your key correctly and there is nothing
>   to be done, other than selecting a different key for your mapping or
>   using GVim, which should recognise the key correctly.

On my setup issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shfit</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> displays 'D', and issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shfit</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> leads to the same result. So at least here Vim is unable to detect the difference.

But maybe you could use some other tool to aid you on this; for instance, on Windows you could try [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with something like this:

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class Vim
LShift & d::MsgBox You pressed the wrong 'Shift'!
#ifWinActive
```

or to simple ignore the combination:

```
#ifWinActive ahk_class Vim
LShift & d::
#ifWinActive
```

Comment: Any suggestion for Mac? I'll wait a while and se of there are other answers. If not I will accept this.

Comment: @Andreas [this site](http://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=mac) lists AHK alternatives for Mac

Comment: I highly recommend Seil (the karabiner's successor) :)

Comment: For OSX there is now Karabiner-Elements with ready-made settings to disable left-shift with right-hand letters etc. https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#key_specific

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, this can be fairly easily accomplished using Karabiner-Elements and goku (better config language for karabiner).
Here's what the relevant bit in my `karabiner.edn` that basically maps all those "bad" shift- combos to nothing looks like:

```
;; Modifiers spec for reference:
;; !  | means mandatory
;; #  | means optional
;; C  | left_command
;; T  | left_control
;; O  | left_option
;; S  | left_shift
;; F  | fn
;; Q  | right_command
;; W  | right_control
;; E  | right_option
;; R  | right_shift
;; P  | caps_lock
;; !! | mandatory command + control + optional + shift (hyper)
;; ## | optional any

             {:des   "mappings"
              :rules [
                      ;; help me get better at not typing shift key on same side of keyboard as key
                      ;; left side
                      [:!Sq []]
                      [:!Sw []]
                      [:!Se []]
                      [:!Sr []]
                      [:!St []]
                      [:!Sa []]
                      [:!Ss []]
                      [:!Sd []]
                      [:!Sf []]
                      [:!Sg []]
                      [:!Sz []]
                      [:!Sx []]
                      [:!Sc []]
                      [:!Sv []]
                      [:!Sb []]
                      [:!S1 []]
                      [:!S2 []]
                      [:!S3 []]
                      [:!S4 []]
                      [:!S5 []]
                      ;; right side
                      [:!Ry []]
                      [:!Ru []]
                      [:!Ri []]
                      [:!Ro []]
                      [:!Rp []]
                      [:!Rh []]
                      [:!Rj []]
                      [:!Rk []]
                      [:!Rl []]
                      [:!Rn []]
                      [:!Rm []]
                      [:!R6 []]
                      [:!R7 []]
                      [:!R8 []]
                      [:!R9 []]
                      [:!R0 []]
                      ]}
```

Useful links:

- karabiner examples: https://github.com/nikitavoloboev/dotfiles/blob/master/karabiner/karabiner.edn
- goku exmamples: https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo/blob/master/examples.org
- goku tutorial: https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo/blob/master/tutorial.md

For reference, here's my full `karabiner.edn`:

```
;; Modifiers spec:
;; !  | means mandatory
;; #  | means optional
;; C  | left_command
;; T  | left_control
;; O  | left_option
;; S  | left_shift
;; F  | fn
;; Q  | right_command
;; W  | right_control
;; E  | right_option
;; R  | right_shift
;; P  | caps_lock
;; !! | mandatory command + control + optional + shift (hyper)
;; ## | optional any
{
 :profiles
            {:Default {:default true
                    :sim     100
                    :delay   500
                    :alone   1000
                    :held    500}}

 :devices {:kinesis-keyboard [{:vendor_id 1523 :product_id 7}]}
            }

 :main      [
             {:des "simultaneous j k press to ESC" :rules [[[:j :k] :escape]]}
             {:des "simultaneous d f press to ctrl-space" :rules [[[:d :f]  {:key :spacebar :modi [:left_control]} ]]}
             {:des "swap end with left option" :rules [[:##end :left_option :kinesis-keyboard]]}
             {:des "swap control and command" :rules [[:##left_control :left_command :kinesis-keyboard]
                                                      [:##right_command :right_control :kinesis-keyboard]
                                                      [:##right_control :right_command :kinesis-keyboard]
                                                      ]}
             {:des "command left/right to opt left/right" :rules [
                                                      [:!Cleft_arrow {:key :left_arrow :modi [:left_option]}]
                                                      [:!Cright_arrow {:key :right_arrow :modi [:left_option]}]
                                                      ]}
             {:des "command backsapce to opt backspace" :rules [
                                                      [:!Cdelete_or_backspace {:key :delete_or_backspace :modi [:left_option]}]
                                                      [:!Qdelete_or_backspace {:key :delete_or_backspace :modi [:left_option]}]
                                                      ]}
             {:des "have home emit CTOS modifiers" :rules [[:##home {:key :left_command :modi [:left_command :left_control :left_option :left_shift]}]]}
             {:des "have caps_lock emit CTOS modifiers" :rules [[:##caps_lock {:key :left_command :modi [:left_command :left_control :left_option :left_shift]}]]}

             {:des   "mappings"
              :rules [
                      ;; help me get better at not typing shift key on same side of keyboard as key
                      ;; left side
                      [:!Sq []]
                      [:!Sw []]
                      [:!Se []]
                      [:!Sr []]
                      [:!St []]
                      [:!Sa []]
                      [:!Ss []]
                      [:!Sd []]
                      [:!Sf []]
                      [:!Sg []]
                      [:!Sz []]
                      [:!Sx []]
                      [:!Sc []]
                      [:!Sv []]
                      [:!Sb []]
                      [:!S1 []]
                      [:!S2 []]
                      [:!S3 []]
                      [:!S4 []]
                      [:!S5 []]
                      ;; right side
                      [:!Ry []]
                      [:!Ru []]
                      [:!Ri []]
                      [:!Ro []]
                      [:!Rp []]
                      [:!Rh []]
                      [:!Rj []]
                      [:!Rk []]
                      [:!Rl []]
                      [:!Rn []]
                      [:!Rm []]
                      [:!R6 []]
                      [:!R7 []]
                      [:!R8 []]
                      [:!R9 []]
                      [:!R0 []]
                      ]}
             ]
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might help if you focus the code snippet to just the relevant bit

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the feedback! I can do that, I was worried that people would find it confusing out of context ... maybe what I'll do is have a focused code snippet first and include the full thing after just for reference.