# Mapping Ctrl with equal sign

Tags: key-bindings, macvim

I am trying to map my Ctrl and plus sign together. This is what I am trying in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-=>    : echo "Hello" <CR>
```

However it seems like the mapping is not being triggered.
Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? I am using macvim.

Comment: [faq 20.4](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4) and [20.5](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5)

Comment: It seems this kind of question is getting more frequent: [VIM how to map the combine key: ctrl+shift+w+,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454831)

Comment: @mMontu Yeah, it's a pretty common question. I wonder if it would be a good idea to write a canonical post on vim's internal representation of characters, termcodes, and what vim can/can't map.

Comment: See also: [key bindings - How to map <C-i> separate from <Tab>? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-map-c-i-separate-from-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- which contains an answer that works by default using `modifyOtherKeys`; [key bindings - Disable <Esc> but keep <C-[> - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/disable-esc-but-keep-c) ■ [key bindings - How to map Alt key? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-map-alt-key)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no reliable way of mapping <kbd>Ctrl-=</kbd>.

Because of the way that `ctrl+key` chords interact with the terminal and are represented internally, the only Ctrl-mappings that Vim is guaranteed to be able to detect are the ones defined in the ASCII standard. Here is the full list of such `ctrl+key` combinations, and the byte each represents.

```
Ctrl-@                 0x00            NUL
Ctrl-A to Ctrl-Z       0x01 to 0x1A
Ctrl-a to Ctrl-z       0x01 to 0x1A
Ctrl-[                 0x1B            ESC
Ctrl-\                 0x1C
Ctrl-]                 0x1D
Ctrl-^                 0x1E
Ctrl-_                 0x1F
Ctrl-?                 0x7F            DEL
```

However, note that most of these are already have a function in Vim, and some are essentially identical to/indistinguishable from other keystrokes. e.g. `CTRL-M` has the same keycode as `Enter`, so if you map either of those you are also unavoidably mapping the other.

Source: [Vim-FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5)

You might be able to get around the restrictions above by configuring your terminal to send a certain byte-sequence for your mapping, like in [this stack-overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179779/3524982), but that will definitely be a pain. Personally, I'd rather just pick a different mapping.

This might eventually be fixed, but it's unlikely, since Vim relies upon the terminal it's running in. However, there's a good possibility this will work in Neovim. I don't know if that works right now or not.