# Mapping Esc+key (hold down escape and press another key to perform action)

Tags: key-bindings

I mapped my capslock key to escape but sometimes I accidentally press capslock when I meant to press shift.

Can I remap `<Esc>+key` to send me back to insert mode and insert the proper character?

For example I would like to press `<Esc>+9` and be put back into insert mode and insert the `(` character (as if I had just pressed `<Shift>+9`).

Possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this is not possible. See [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8857/6489).

Comment: @Tumbler41 Isn't that about mapping to `ctrl` rather than `<esc>`?

Comment: "I mapped my capslock key to escape" -> How did you do this? In Vim or in your operating system?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I thought that wasn't possible to do that in Vim and doing it in the OS level was the only way. Have I missed something?

Comment: @statox Dunno ... But seems to me that asking to be sure is always a good idea ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I can only agree with that :)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I was more referring to the part that about "Vim relies on ASCII representations of keystrokes." Since `<Esc>` Is it's own ASCII byte, it can't be chained with other characters.

Comment: @Tumbler41 it doesn't affect *this* question, but note that that part of that answer is inaccurate. (See my more recent comment on the answer).

Comment: It seems to me that the best place to perform this mapping is *outside* of Vim, in whatever software you used to remap your Caps Lock key in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`<Esc>` is not a modifier like <kbd>Shift</kbd>. There's no `<Esc-9>` keycode, only `<S-9>`.

As you usually press Shift *before* the other key, you could approach this via a set of sequential mappings:

```
:inoremap <Esc>9 (
:inoremap <Esc>0 )
...
```

But that would introduce a noticeable delay when you really just want to leave insert mode.

Comment: I just tried this (in terminal and gVim), and it only works if I release the Escape key before pressing the 9 key. (If I hold down Escape I only get a 9 inserted.) I'm not clear if that's your intention, or if there's a some setting that affects this behaviour?

Comment: @Rich That's what I meant by "not a modifier". You have to press them sequentially; there's no setting within Vim.

Comment: The way you've written the second paragraph made me think that you were saying your mapping would work both if the key presses were pressed sequentially (hence, "not a modifier"), but *also* if the key-presses overlapped, so long as Escape was pressed first. Thanks for clarifying.