# Remap left arrow to ctrl key in vim

Tags: vimrc

On macbook keyboard, there is only one ctrl key on the left.  I am so used to  for half page down using the right ctrl key that it is driving me crazy.   Any way to remap the left key to ctrl?

Comment: Unfortunately [there is no way to remap the ctrl key in vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8857/6489).

Comment: Ok, so how can I  do the <left-d> to half page down?

Comment: @user1135541 You can't. At least not in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While (post-experimentation and reading) I have found no way to remap `<Left>` to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, I can at least point you in two different directions:

#### Simple mapping

You can "simulate" this with some mappings for common tasks, like

```
nnoremap <silent> <Left>d <C-d>
```

The downside is that you'll need to do this for any and all commands you want to map.

#### OS Keymap

While off-topic here, the internet and other stackexchange sites have lots of information on changing your keyboard layout (especially for modifier keys).

For example, I use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>: it saves me a lot of pinky strain.