# Cannot map Ctrl+ number (except 6 or ^)

Tags: key-bindings

I am using macvim 8.1, the map command is

```
:inoremap <C-$> <End>
```

I also tried `<C-4>`, no working.

tried other number, can't work too (however CTRL-6 could work).

Also tried `nnoremap`, same result.

the `:map <C-$>` command shows

```
i <C-$>      * <End>
```

Comment: Related question: [key bindings - Mapping Ctrl with equal sign - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 9):

Normally Ctrl-Number produce a different key code. You can check like this:

Open Vim and change to insert mode. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-4</kbd> (or whatever you plan to map).

On Linux this produces the output `^\`. Note that this is one character, usually displayed in light-blue. So <kbd>Ctrl-4</kbd> is identical to <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>.

Tested with Vim 8.1 on Ubuntu in Gnome-Terminal (but *should* be true for all systems):

- <kbd>Ctrl-1</kbd>  is not detected
- <kbd>Ctrl-2</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-@</kbd> (hex `0x00`)
- <kbd>Ctrl-3</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> aka <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-4</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-5</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-7</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-_</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-8</kbd>  is <kbd>Ctrl-?</kbd> aka <kbd>Delete</kbd> used as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl-9</kbd>  is not detected
- <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd>  is not detected

Comment: Also, please see the faq: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: If `Ctrl-3` is identical to `ESC`, I should expect vim quit insert mode to normal mode when `Ctrl-3` is pressed, like `ESC` usuallly does, however, actually, `3` is input, so `Ctrl-3` shouldn't be the same as `ESC` or `Ctrl-[`, should it?

Comment: @chrisyue `<Ctrl-3>` leaves insert mode. Tested in Vim, GVim, and the vi-editing-mode of Bash (Gnome-Terminal, XTerm).

Comment: Well, on a mac at least `<C-6>` doesnt work, you have to use `<C-^>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, when I wanted to map <kbd>Ctrl+4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+6</kbd> keys, but those codes were not recognized. The output of <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+4</kbd> was `^[[1;5t`, which usually would lead to a mapping like e.g.

```
map ^[[1;5t <End>
```

but that did not work. The solution was to replace `^[` with `<ESC>` in the mapping command, like e.g.:

```
map <ESC>[1;5t <End>
imap <ESC>[1;5t <End>
```

Comment: Note: ■ Generally speaking, mapping raw key sequences like shown is not a good idea, as then pressing <esc> will be delayed. ■ of course you can write `^[` directly in vim editor, just enter it as the raw escape byte (by <c-v><esc>, the `^[` should be colored blue)