# Map CTRL-& in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'm trying to re-map [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) toggling with `<C-&>` that I get used to when working with IDEs.

But setting

```
execute "nnoremap <C-&> :TagbarToggle<CR>"
```

does not have the desirable effect. When pressing 3 keys at once `CTRL-SHIFT-7` where `SHIFT-7` stands for `&` it essentially acts as simple pressing `&` without `CTRL`.

Is there a way `<C-&>` to behave differently other than `&`?

Comment: For xterm there's a stack overflow answer linked from [key bindings - Mapping Ctrl with equal sign - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign?noredirect=1&lq=1) that allows changing the key that the terminal sends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [one of our former mods](https://bestasciitable.com), the answer is no:

> Sending Control with a character from the 2nd column is useless. Control clears the 7th bit, but this is already 0, so Control+# will just send "#".

Notice that `&` in the second column has binary representation `01 00110`, so clearing the `0` doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.