# How to map the slash key "/"

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to map the NERDCommenterToggle command from the [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) plugin. I want to use "Ctrl+/" for this:

```
vmap <C-/> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
nmap <C-/> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

This won't work, I guess there should be some other name to map the slash key... I've already tried to find some info with :help, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Mapping `/` is possible (although not really recommended) but mapping `<c-/>` is probably not possible in terminal version of vim (unlike the gui one). This is a common problem of key codes (I tried to list some in [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)) so it is very likely that you can only have this mapping working in GUI version of Vim (or neovim).

Comment: I am currently using neovim, how can it be done here?

Comment: In this regard the behavior is the same between vim and neovim.

Comment: It depends on the gui. It should be possible in gvim and xterm with modifyOtherKeys. Don't think Neovim supports this

Comment: [Can confirm](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6191#issuecomment-655013133) that you can map `<c-/>` in Vim in the GUI (at least if it's GTK2), and in a terminal where modifyOtherKeys is supported and enabled (xterm and maybe iterm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Ctrl with equal sign](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign).

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26611/is-it-possible-to-map-control-forward-slash-with-vim Use <C-_> and it'll probably work